# Error 403 when calling Udemy API but on localhost it still works

Tags: python, fastapi

Currently I'm working on a project about "Automatically Enroll free coupons" from Udemy

I am using Fastapi on the backend and React on the frontend

> main.py

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
   CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = ["*"],
    allow_credentials =True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers= ["*"],
)

class LoginItem(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    client_id: str

@app.post("/api/check-login")
def check_login(input_token: LoginItem):
    s = requests.Session()
    data = jsonable_encoder(input_token)
    cookies = dict(client_id=data['client_id'], access_token=data['access_token'])
    url_checklogin = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/contexts/me/?header=True"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data['access_token'],
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5",
        "Referer": "https://www.udemy.com/",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    }
    resp = s.get(url_checklogin,headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.json()
    else:
        return {"status_code": resp.status_code, "text": resp.text}
```

> App.jsx

```
    function App() {
     const [token, setToken] = useState("");
     const [csrfToken, setCsrfToken] = useState("");
    
     const backend_url = "https://backen-udemycoupon.vercel.app";
        
     const handleSubmit = async () => {
     const url_login = backend_url + "/api/check-login";
     let res = await axios.post(url_login, {
          access_token: token,
          client_id: csrfToken,
        });
        
     console.log("check log", res.data);
    };
    
    return (
      <>
       <div className="form-group mb-3">
           <label className="form-label">Access_token</label>
           <input
               type="text"
               className="form-control"
               onChange={(event) => setToken(event.target.value)}
           />
       </div>
       <div className="form-group mb-3">
           <label className="form-label">Client_id</label>
           <input
               type="text"
               className="form-control"
               onChange={(event) => setCsrfToken(event.target.value)}
            />
       </div>
       <button onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>
              Login
       </button >
    </>
   )
 }
```

When I run on "http://localhost:8000" I log in normally.

But when I switched to the server that I uploaded to Vercel "https://backen-udemycoupon.vercel.app/" then get error 403 Forbidden

The udemy link below and the parameters passed:

```
url_checklogin = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/contexts/me/?header=True"
```

I took a look at it above:

https://github.com/techtanic/Discounted-Udemy-Course-Enroller/blob/master/base.py (at line 599 of code)

Now I don't know how to fix error 403. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me fix this problem.